# ggplot2 extension with log xy scales using ggproto

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

is it possible to make a ggplot2 extension (ex. geom_smooth) that converts the existing xy axes into log10 scales automatically?

here's a reprex for example

```
set.seed(11) # generate random data
method1 = c(rnorm(19,0,1),2.5)
method2 = c(rnorm(19,0,1),2.5)
Subject <- rep(paste0('S',seq(1:20)), 2)
Data <- data.frame(Value = matrix(c(method1,method2),ncol=1))
Method <- rep(c('Method 1', 'Method 2'), each = length(method1))
df_corr <- data.frame(first = method1, second = method2) # used for correlation

ggplot(data = df_corr, mapping = aes(x = first, y = second)) +
  geom_smooth() + # line 2
  scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10') +  # line 3
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10') # line4
```

Instead I would like to create a ggplot2 extension function (that receives all the aesthetics defined by `ggplot2()`) that does what lines 2-4 at once using **ggproto**.

Comment: Can you explain why you're looking for a solution with ggproto and the suggested answers don't sufficiently address the reason why you'd like to use ggproto?

Comment: The reason I think the idea might require further thought, is because the core concept of the grammar of graphics, on which ggplot2 is based, is that layers like geometries should be independently defined from scales and their transformations. Joining these in a ggproto class would be confusing to anyone comfortable with ggplot2.

Comment: you raise a good point, I just wanted to try to it and got stuck, thanks for your thoughts

Answer (score 2):

You could also throw the three lines into a list:

```
geom_smooth_log <- list(
  geom_smooth(), # line 2
    scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10'),  # line 3
    scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10') # line4
)

ggplot(data = df_corr, mapping = aes(x = first, y = second)) +
  geom_smooth_log
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I meant creating an extension using ggproto

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own function in the following manner:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(11) # generate random data
method1 = c(rnorm(19,0,1),2.5)
method2 = c(rnorm(19,0,1),2.5)
Subject <- rep(paste0('S',seq(1:20)), 2)
Data <- data.frame(Value = matrix(c(method1,method2),ncol=1))
Method <- rep(c('Method 1', 'Method 2'), each = length(method1))
df_corr <- data.frame(first = method1, second = method2) # used for correlation

my_log_plot <- function(data, x, y) {
  ggplot(data, aes({{x}}, {{y}})) +
    geom_smooth() +
    scale_x_log10() +
    scale_y_log10()
}

my_log_plot(df_corr, first, second)
```

[image]

To create your own `ggplot` function, you need to use `ggproto`, and the process is outlined [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html).

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I was looking for a possible solution using ggproto